# Problema al utilizar AJAX con conexión PDO

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

Saludos, estoy teniendo problemas al realizar peticiones AJAX a PHP, utilizando una conexión a la bd con PDO. Al momento de poner en ejecución el Login, se me queda **Validando...** y no me da ninguna respuesta.. Este es el código.

```
try{ 
    $this->con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=poo_pdo','root',''); 
    }catch(PDOExcepcion $e){ 
        echo $e->getMessage(); 
    exit; 
    }
```

AJAX:

```
jQuery(document).on('submit','#login_admin', function(event){
event.preventDefault();

jQuery.ajax({
  url:'Controllers/procesar_login.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  beforeSend: function(){
    $('#entrar').val('Validando...');
    $('#entrar').attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
})
.done(function(respuesta){
    if(respuesta.tipo == 'administrador'){
        $('#alerta_ok').slideDown('slow');
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('#alerta_ok').slideUp('slow');
          location.href = 'admin/admin.php';
        },4000);
    }else{
        $('#alerta_err').slideDown('slow');
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('#alerta_err').slideUp('slow');
        },4000);
      $('#entrar').removeAttr("disabled");
        $('#entrar').val('Entrar');
    }
  })
});
```

PHP:

```
  if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){
  require('../Conexion.php');

  sleep(2);

  $con->set_charset('utf8');

  $usuario = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['admin_usuario']);
  $pass = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['admin_clave']);

   if($new_consulta = $con->prepare("SELECT tkd_admin.admin_nombre, 
   tkd_admin.admin_usuario, tkd_admin.admin_clave, tkd_admin.tkd_idperfil, 
   tkd_perfiles.perfiles FROM  tkd_perfiles INNER JOIN tkd_admin 
   ON tkd_perfiles.idperfil = tkd_admin.tkd_idperfil 
   WHERE tkd_admin.admin_usuario = ? AND tkd_admin.admin_clave = ?")){
   $new_consulta->bind_param('ss',$usuario,$pass);

   $new_consulta->execute();

   $result = $new_consulta->get_result();

   if($result->num_rows>0){
    $datos = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $datos;
    echo json_encode(array('error'=>false,'tipo'=>$datos['perfiles']));
   }else{
    echo json_encode(array('error'=>true));
    echo mysqli_error($con);
   }
   $new_consulta->close();
  }
 }
 $con->close();
?>
```

Eso es todo lo que tengo, como he dicho mi boton se queda Validando, y no me da ninguna respuesta, lo unico que tengo es esto que me lo arroja en console

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ni siquiera me imprime el json, ni nada. Y para prueba he colocado new mysqli de conexion y si funciona bien. No se si es problemas con el ajax que estoy usando. Agradeceria mucho de su ayuda en esto.

Comment: Te funciona pdo con mysqli pero con mysql no?

Comment: No, me funciona el AJAX utilizando la conexion de tipo new mysqli, pero el AJAX con conexion new PDO no me funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no has migrado tu código a PDO realmente. Sigues usando funciones de `mysqli` con PDO.

En PDO las cosas son algo diferentes con respecto a mysqli.

Prueba a hacerlo de este modo.

Te comento los cambios principales:

- Puedes establecer el juego de caracteres en la cadena DSN que pasas al crear la conexión.
- No necesitas escapar nada, de eso se encarga el `prepare`, que para eso existe
- `bind_param` no es para PDO. Sería `bindParam`, pero tampoco es necesario, ya que con PDO puedes pasar los parámetros en forma de array en el mismo `execute` sin ningún riesgo.
- `get_result` es un método propio de mysqli. Con PDO debes usar alguno de los métodos `fetch`. Aquí usaremos `fetchAll`, que sería el método más parecido a `get_result`.
- El manejo de errores que haces tampoco funciona con PDO. Debes usar para este caso `errorInfo`.
- En PDO, no se cierra la conexión con `close` sino que se destruye la instancia del objeto, asignándole `NULL`. Lo mismo ocurre que el objeto que se obtiene del método `prepare`.

Creo que es lo principal.

Prueba con este código. Asumiendo que se conecta bien, debería funcionar.

#### Conexión

```
try{ 
    $this->con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=poo_pdo;charset=utf8','root',''); 
    }catch(PDOExcepcion $e){ 
        echo $e->getMessage(); 
    exit; 
    }
```

#### Código de la consulta

```
  if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){
  require('../Conexion.php');

  sleep(2);

  $usuario = $_POST['admin_usuario'];
  $pass = $_POST['admin_clave'];

   if($new_consulta = $con->prepare("SELECT tkd_admin.admin_nombre, 
   tkd_admin.admin_usuario, tkd_admin.admin_clave, tkd_admin.tkd_idperfil, 
   tkd_perfiles.perfiles FROM  tkd_perfiles INNER JOIN tkd_admin 
   ON tkd_perfiles.idperfil = tkd_admin.tkd_idperfil 
   WHERE tkd_admin.admin_usuario = ? AND tkd_admin.admin_clave = ?")){

   $arrParams=array($usuario,$pass);

   $new_consulta->execute($arrParams);

   $datos = $new_consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

   if($datos){
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $result;
    echo json_encode(array('error'=>false,'tipo'=>$datos['perfiles']));
   }else{
    echo json_encode(array('error'=>true, 'mensaje'=>$new_consulta->errorInfo()[2]));
   }
   $new_consulta=NULL;
  }
 }
 $con=NULL;
?>
```

Comment: Absoluta razón tienes A. Cedano. Era por eso, y también ese método close() no es de PDO, ese era el error también. Gracias por tu respuesta y orientación. Acertado como siempre.

Comment: Cierto @AlejoMendoza, hay que destruir la instancia del objeto con `NULL` si se quiere. Ya he editado esa parte. Saludos.

Comment: Exacto @A. Cedano. Por cierto me esta dando un problema en 'tipo'=>$datos['perfiles']. El network me arroja que la perfiles esta indefinida. Como si no estuviese ese dato en el arreglo

Comment: Ya he resuelto eso @A. Cedano, cambie el fetchAll por fetch, asumi que como solo estoy buscando un solo registro podia usar el fetch, y ha funcionado